# Shared memory C++ and Win API 32 with custom class

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, shared-memory

Are there any samples with getting custom class including large arrays as properties in shared memory? I need read/write access from different threads in same process. Size of class instance is unknown at compilation time. OpenMP solutions are not allowed in my case, just win 32 API or native c++ features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need shared memory for this. All memory in one c++ process is implicitly shared and is accessible by all threads, as far as they know its address.

What you really need is synchronization so threads access objects in proper order (without race condition). Your objects should implement so-called  [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) pattern.

In c++ you do this manually like this

- put (win32 API) mutex as a member of your object
- lock this mutex in the very beginning of every method
- unlock it at method exit. It's better to use locker object on the stack to deal with exceptions.

(in some languages you could just declare methods or objects synchronized, but in c++ you do this manually)

Alternatively use higher level parallel pattern, like 'readers/writers'.
I prefer message passing

Comment: +1 Depending on the conditions in which it is used, a simple CRITICAL_SECTION in a win32 application may well give a substantial performance boost rather than using a mutex, but the general point of this answer is correct; you do not need shared memory for a multi-*threaded* win32 application unless you're planning on also sharing the data with another *process* (at which point the critical section is out as well, and you should use a mutex).